# Android Gradle - Gitlab CI - Docker - CMake - NullPointerException

Tags: nullpointerexception, cmake, android-gradle-plugin, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to get simple Android Unit Tests to run on Gitlab CI, but I'm having troubles getting things to build correctly in the CI Docker image.  I have the `master` project which pulls from a `Library` project.  The Library has C code in it, so I need to use CMake to get it to build.  All of this is working locally on my windows machine when using Android Studio.  However, once I move to the CI server, things break with the following error:

```
Using incremental javac compilation for :Library debug.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
Checking the license for package CMake 3.6.3155560 in /android-sdk-linux/licenses
License for package CMake 3.6.3155560 accepted.
Preparing "Install CMake 3.6.3155560 (revision: 3.6.3155560)".
"Install CMake 3.6.3155560 (revision: 3.6.3155560)" ready.
Finishing "Install CMake 3.6.3155560 (revision: 3.6.3155560)"
Installing CMake 3.6.3155560 in /android-sdk-linux/cmake/3.6.3155560
"Install CMake 3.6.3155560 (revision: 3.6.3155560)" complete.
"Install CMake 3.6.3155560 (revision: 3.6.3155560)" finished.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':Library'.
> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':Library'.
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:94)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:89)
    ...
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.builder.sdk.DefaultSdkLoader.installSdkTool(DefaultSdkLoader.java:572)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.SdkHandler.installCMake(SdkHandler.java:302)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ExternalNativeJsonGenerator.create(ExternalNativeJsonGenerator.java:628)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.TaskManager.createExternalNativeBuildJsonGenerators(TaskManager.java:1241)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.LibraryTaskManager.lambda$createTasksForVariantData$11(LibraryTaskManager.java:240)
    ...
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:82)
    ... 56 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1 mins 25.384 secs
Stopped 0 worker daemon(s).
Received result Failure[value=org.gradle.initialization.ReportedException: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: A problem occurred configuring project ':Library'.] from daemon DaemonInfo{pid=39, address=[1f3b75f9-7080-48b5-b298-0e6136640a0a port:41964, addresses:[/127.0.0.1]],     state=Busy, lastBusy=1496784783851, context=DefaultDaemonContext[uid=0e3eadf0-a7bd-4ede-9eb8-0c2a96ebef58,javaHome=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64,daemonRegistryDir=/root/.gradle/daemon,pid=39,idleTimeout=10800000,daemonOpts=-Xmx1536m,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country,-Duser.language=en,    -Duser.variant]} (build should be done).
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Judging by the line

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.builder.sdk.DefaultSdkLoader.installSdkTool(DefaultSdkLoader.java:572)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.SdkHandler.installCMake(SdkHandler.java:302)
```

it looks like it is a problem with the CMake.  But it looks like it is installed and the licence is accepted as noted by the output at the start of that block above.

---

Can anyone give me some pointers on what is the problem?
* Is it that gradle doesn't know where CMake was installed?
* Is it a problem perhaps with the NDK?
* Or perhaps where I can find the source code for `com.android.build.gradle.internal.SdkHandler.installCMake` and `com.android.builder.sdk.DefaultSdkLoader.installSdkTool`.
My searches have been unfruitful.

I can provide more about my setup upon request. (i.e. android project, docker image, gitlab-ci.yml, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Well, [mbertin](https://github.com/mbertin) commented on Feb 2 at [here](https://github.com/bitrise-io/build.issues/issues/33) that by using a lower gradle build tool, it solved the problem for him.  (i.e. `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2`).

After giving it an attempt, my build script got passed that error!  (anyone know why?)

Thanks for the emotional support Stack Overflow! You are the best!